# Let $(L, <)$ be an uncountable Linear order then is the following claim true?

Tags: set-theory

For Every Uncountable Linear order $(L,<)$ there exist a uncountable subset $X$ of $L$ such that $X$ is well ordered by $<$

I need to prove/disprove above claim

Here is my attempt on this question :

Let $a \in L$, then we consider the initial segment $Y = \text{pred}(X,<,a)$ if this segment is countable then I can consider

$Z =L-Y$ this will be a well ordered set, as it will have $a$ as its least- member and will be uncountable

the problem is I am not sure how to produce such as a initial segment ,so I cannot proceed further in this question.

Since , I am a beginner in set theory it will be helpful if someone can give a proper solution to understand the subject better and I can use the techniques in solving future problems

Comment: The real numbers with their usual ordering is another counterexample.

Answer (score 3):

Hagen von Eitzen's example works, but isn't using the full power which well-orderings provide us:

> Suppose $\alpha$ is a "co-well-ordering," that is, a linear order in which every nonempty subset has a *maximum* element. Then every ascending sequence in $\alpha$ is finite.

This is the same exact argument as the proof that every descending sequence in a well-ordering is finite. From this we then get:

> Suppose $\alpha$ is a co-well-ordering. Then $\alpha$ has no **infinite** (let alone uncountable) suborders which are well-orders.

This is because if $\beta$ is an infinite well-ordering, then $\beta$ contains an infinite ascending sequence (think about the "first $\omega$-many elements").

So we can improve Hagen's example as follows:

> If $\alpha$ is a co-well-ordering (not necessarily minimal) then $\alpha$ has no infinite (let alone uncountable) well-ordered suborder.

Answer (score 1):

Let $L$ be the smallest uncountable ordinal, but $<$ is the reverse order.
Assume $X\subseteq L$ has  a minimal element $x_0=\min X$ (which is certainly the case if $X$ is well-ordered by $<$).
By construction, there are only countable may $y\in L$ with $y>x$, hence $X$ is countable.

Comment: I don't understand the last part of the argument "by construction there are only countably many $y \in L$ with $y > x$,"

Comment: @total_beginner Remember that $L$ is the *smallest* uncountable ordinal: any proper initial segment of $L$ (= any proper *final* segment of the *reverse* of $L$) is countable.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Can you explain  what is the "reverse order"  used here ? according  to my understanding , ordinals have a predefined order ie    $ 0 < 1< 2 <3 \ldots < \omega..$ , . Are we defining a  new  ordering on the set of ordinals ?

Comment: @total_beginner Read the first sentence of Hagen's answer. He's defining a new linear ordering whose underlying set is the same as that of the first uncountable ordinal but whose order relation is the opposite of that of the first uncountable ordinal.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Ok, just to make sure I understand this correctly , in the usual order relation for ordinals we say , $x < y$ if $x \in y$, here since we are reversing the order this becomes $x < y$ if  $y \in x$ .                                                                                                       Is this correct ?

Comment: @total_beginner Exactly. For clarity though we should be careful not to use the same symbol for each, which is why this answer explicitly defines "$<$" to refer to the *latter*.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Thank you, for your kind help.

Comment: @total_beginner In fact we can get a stronger result using the same idea; see my answer.